# PHP - Get string from URL

Tags: php, http

by having an URL like this: mysite.com/subfolder/helloworld - Is it possible to read the "helloworld" from within a PHP page?

I would like to use the string as a part to load some content.

Comment: you could make use of a .htaccess file to use url rewriting (mod_rewrite) and pass the query string (i.e. /subfolder/helloworld) as a parameter to a php file of your choosing.

Answer (score 2):

```
end( explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )
```

without the end() call it will give you all the parts of the URL

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [URL rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_rewriting).

This is more clean than "reading" the current URL. Basically you can redirect your URL (transparently) to something like :

```
mysite.com/index.php?folder=subfolder&category=helloworld
```

Then in PHP, you can access the URL parameter with :

```
$folder = $_GET['subfolder']
$category = $_GET['category']
```

This is maybe not the kind of answer you were expecting, but it can be interesting to know.

Answer (score 0):

The request url (everything from the first / after the domain name) can be found in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Comment: @Oerd That sounds interesting. I'ld like to try that. How does the .htaccess file would look like to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hello have u used 'strstr' keyword of php?
please try like this

```
if(strstr($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], "helloworld"))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

May be this will be helpful to you.